# Find out if a specific time frame is free in an array

Tags: java, methods, parameters

This "flying-club" project, is to help flight-club personal to manage their work, so there are a couple of methods to serve this purpose and do so.  However, I am a java-junior and not familiar quite well with the flexibility of java and its functions when it comes to a bit harder tasks like the following one: this method should check if any flight is free in a specific time frame (given by user) and print out those who actually are and if there are none, it should print out(there is unfortunately none for this time frame that can be booked). On several ways and in different methods have i taken a try but none of them work:

The method:

```
public static void rentFlight(int[] flightQuantity, String[] identification, String[] time, int index, boolean free) throws ParseException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which flight would you like to rent (enter the number of it)");
        index = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("For when are you renting the flight: (hh:mm)");
        String z = sc.nextLine(); // time frame given
        for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) { // iterate through the time array 
            if (!z.contains(String.valueOf(time))) { // if the time given doesn't match in any way, then the flight is free
                System.out.println("The flight is free and can be rented: " + identification[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is unfortunately no free flights");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

the method where the paramteres are getting filled by input from the user:

```
public static void rentAll(int[] flightQuantity, String[] identification, String[] time, String[] name, String[] surname, int index, boolean free) throws ParseException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < flightQuantity.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("flight number: " + flugAnzahl[i]);
            index++;
            System.out.println("flight description: " + bezeichnung[i]);
            System.out.println("At which time would you like to rent the flight");
            System.out.println("enter the time as following: (hh:mm)");
            time[i] = sc.nextLine();
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            Date time2 = ft.parse(time[i]);
            System.out.println(ft.format(time2));
            Date dJetzt = new Date();
            System.out.println("the time now is: " + ft.format(dJetzt));
            System.out.println("the name of the person: ");
            name[i + 1] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("the surname of the person ");
            surname[i + 1] = sc.nextLine();
        }
```

Comment: @user i will do, thought maybe the context would make sense.

Comment: if your program needs to handle dates and time, then make use of what java provides. Have a look at the java.time package. There you will fix classes and methods to help you find x for time range y (yes x can be flights...). But then of course you will have to introduce so that your program knows when a flight is due in time first...